# viewDidLoad of my RootViewController gets called by application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and applicationDidBecomeActive:

Tags: ios, storyboard, startup, viewdidload

I am using a Storyboard with a `UINavigationController` that is set as "is initial View Controller". It's attached RootViewControllers. `viewDidLoad` method gets called after `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and `applicationDidBecomeActive:`.

Why does that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Because the view is loaded before your application becomes active. Active is defined as the point at which your application begins responding to events, and you need a view for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know why `viewDidLoad` method gets called after those methed I suggest you to read the [app-launch-sequence-ios](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/06/app-launch-sequence-ios/). It's the normal bootstrap execeution in every iOS application.

When you istantiate a controller with an associated view, the view for that controller takes some time to load in memory. `viewDidLoad` is not called immediately but only when the view has been loaded completely. Here you are sure that outlet for that view are linked correctly.

Hope it helps.